# 3d Plotting in R based on a logical statement

Tags: r, plot, 3d, large-data

I have a huge data frame with over 300 entries. I am trying to 3d plot a select few data point based on the time in which the points were collected.

This is a window of the data frame and I want to plot the X, Y and Z Positions based on the time points. (This data frame has more than the 2 time points shown here)

```js
  Position.X Position.Y Position.Z Unit Category Collection Time Parent ID NUMB
1 -19557.15 -8140.369 2743.270 um Spot Position 2 1e+09 0 1
2 -19557.85 -8135.700 2743.270 um Spot Position 3 1e+09 1 2
3 -19555.22 -8141.372 2738.270 um Spot Position 4 1e+09 2 3
4 -19556.40 -8141.744 2738.270 um Spot Position 5 1e+09 3 4
5 -19554.08 -8143.750 2738.270 um Spot Position 6 1e+09 4 5
6 -19555.66 -8144.278 2743.270 um Spot Position 7 1e+09 5 6
7 -19556.90 -8148.024 2738.270 um Spot Position 8 1e+09 6 7
8 -19556.53 -8149.604 2738.270 um Spot Position 9 1e+09 7 8
9 -19556.52 -8149.210 2738.270 um Spot Position 10 1e+09 8 9
10 -19556.11 -8148.038 2738.270 um Spot Position 11 1e+09 9 10
11 -19556.49 -8147.759 2743.270 um Spot Position 12 1e+09 10 11
12 -19554.93 -8147.398 2743.270 um Spot Position 13 1e+09 11 12
13 -19555.27 -8143.897 2743.270 um Spot Position 14 1e+09 12 13
14 -19556.75 -8138.987 2738.270 um Spot Position 15 1e+09 13 14
15 -19557.84 -8134.924 2743.270 um Spot Position 16 1e+09 14 15
16 -19555.56 -8137.831 2738.270 um Spot Position 17 1e+09 15 16
17 -19557.19 -8143.085 2743.270 um Spot Position 18 1e+09 16 17
18 -19558.94 -8149.851 2733.270 um Spot Position 19 1e+09 17 18
19 -19541.28 -8141.018 2733.270 um Spot Position 2 1e+09 18 19
20 -19547.46 -8122.667 2738.270 um Spot Position 3 1e+09 19 20
21 -19547.20 -8131.303 2738.270 um Spot Position 4 1e+09 20 21
22 -19547.50 -8130.971 2733.270 um Spot Position 5 1e+09 21 22
23 -19550.37 -8132.817 2738.270 um Spot Position 6 1e+09 22 23
24 -19554.72 -8134.704 2738.270 um Spot Position 7
```

At first I tried

```js
> scatterplot3d(Allcells.csv$Position.X,Allcells.csv$Position.Y,Allcells.csv$Position.Z[Allcells.csv$Time == 2, ] )
```

but I'm having no luck and trouble finding the solution in plotting or a logical statement forum.

Answer (score 0):

You only subsetted the z coordinate instead of the x, y, and z coordinates. Either subset the x, y, and z or have an intermediate step:

```
Somecells <- Allcells.csv[Allcells.csv$Time == 2, ] 
scatterplot3d(Somecells$Position.X,Somecells$Position.Y,Somecells$Position.Z)
```